# What happens if I swap the power supplies on am OP-AMP?

Tags: operational-amplifier, pcb

[image]

I designed a simple audio amplifier - for learning purpose.
After getting PCBs made, I realized some critical errors and stupidities in my design.

One of the mistakes I made is that +12V and -12V are swapped (not to mention I shorted +12 to the inverting input of the op-amp).

After populating the components, I turned on the power supply. It wasn't getting warm or anything, so I plugged in my iPod. Then the OP-AMP and the PCB got really hot!

So now I am curious if my OP-AMP survived this ordeal. I am too afraid to find out by dropping the OP-AMP onto a redesigned PCB.

Comment: You most likely cooked the op-amp.

Comment: You've probably toasted all the protection diodes and any surrounding silicon.

Comment: I see. Sad, but I expected it! Thanks Dwayne and Ignacio.

Comment: Fix the supply rails via PCB surgery.  Hopefully, you have a spare OpAmp.  *p.s.*  This illustrates why negative should be drawn below positive in the schematics.

Comment: Nick I'm not sure how to approach this surgery. It's going to be a major one. I don't see how it can be done on PCB level. And remember that I also shorted the positive supply with the inverting input. And yes I think I was foolishly looking at the polarity of the inputs when I connected my supplies.

Comment: To break unwanted connection, you can cut traces on the PCB with an Xacto knife or a Dremel tool.  To create new connections, solder wire (usually 30AWG wire-wrap is used for this, and usually it's blue, hence "*to blue wire*" is used as a verb in the industry).

Comment: Ok I will try that. Need to get an exacto knife first I suppose. Thanks for the pointers Nick.

Comment: If C3 isn't in your "critical errors and stupidities" list, check for its polarity: it is inverted too (althoug this one is easy to fix: just solder/position your cap. in the oposite direction).

Comment: richardo, yes I noticed my cap on the negative power rail is flipped. Just one of many mistakes... no biggie =P